# How to assign same image for multiple products without creating different image directory

Tags: magento2, product-images, media-images, import-products

Heii new to Magento
I have product with same images for multiple products  but after i upload products via csv it creates seprate image directory for the products in var/cache/

Not a developer but it's the only problem I can't solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create one root file and paste below code in that file and run file in browser OR you can create one custom module and apply this code for one image assign to multiple products.

This code help to you.

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
set_time_limit(0);
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap     = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$dir = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$imagePath = $dir->getPath('media')."/yourimage.jpg"; // Your image should be on pub/media path
$imageType = ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'];

if($collection->getSize()) {
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        if($product->getId()) {
            if(file_exists($imagePath)) {
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, $imageType, false, false);
                $product->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```